# xpath with curl gives empty result?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, curl

This code gives me an empty result. I expect it to print out the titles from the XML-file. I need to use Curl to get the file.

```
<?php    
function get_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$xml_content = get_url("http://www.e24.se/?service=rss&type=latest");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadXML($xml_content);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$results = $xpath->query('//channel//title/text()');


foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    echo $result->title . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it already. The loop is wrong. It should be...

```
foreach ($results as $result) 
{
    echo $result->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```